# Binding not work when initial the context with USING Statement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a binding problem, when I initial a context with `using` statement, The binding for patient name appear empty if I used the following code:

```
using (myEntities context = new myEntities ())
  {
      IQueryable<Appointment> query = context.Appointments.Where(s => s.AppointmentDate == _activeDate);
      ocAppointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(query);

      lbShiftAppointments.ItemsSource = ocAppointments.Where(s => s.DoctorShift.ShiftNumber == 1);
  }
```

But if I initial the context without `using` statment the binding works:

```
myEntities context = new myEntities ();

IQueryable<Appointment> query= context.Appointments.Where(s => s.AppointmentDate == _activeDate);
ocAppointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(query);

lbShiftAppointments.ItemsSource = ocAppointments.Where(s => s.DoctorShift.ShiftNumber == 1);
```

This is the Listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbShiftAppointments" Style="{StaticResource GridBody}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnShiftAppointment">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding patient.name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm confused, any help

---

**UPDATE**
I uploaded a small WPF application with my issue, You can download from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_4ruzpLLeCmv-xOGofJHi_xBkbT-X14L)

Comment: Because `using` means disposing the object immediately after the code block is executed.

Comment: @aepot Even  if I assign the listbox itemsource out of using, binding still not working

Comment: Try `lbShiftAppointments.ItemsSource = ocAppointments.Where(s => s.DoctorShift.ShiftNumber == 1).ToList();`

Comment: @Clemens Nothing happen :(

Comment: @ASh Nothing happen :(

Comment: assigning object means copying the pointer to the instance but not the object cloning. You should clone the data explicitly as @Clemens suggested above.

Comment: @aepot I tried to add .ToList() as Clemens & ASh said but it does not work, But why it works in the second code without using USING statements !!?

Comment: @aepot Note that this has nothing to do with cloning objects. `ToList()` simply forces enumeration of the source IEnumerable.

Comment: Add breakpoint, and debug it then :)

Comment: @Clemens it will not help to avoid disposing of data then.

Comment: @aepot What I am trying to say is that you should avoid posting confusing comments.

Comment: @Clemens i'm not stupid but didn't meet the `ToList()` with `IDisposable` case. Thank you for corrections, God of C#. Meanwhile your suggestion didn't work. Who's confusing?

Comment: Nothing helped me ~ What you suggest ?, When I debug the ItemsSource has 2 record and appear in the ListBox but the patient name not appear empty

Comment: We can't help you without more details. What is myEntities? How does the patient property look like? Does it perhaps require an existing (i.e. non-disposed) myEntities?

Comment: @Clemens myEntities is a entity data module that represented my database schema, I have Appointment table and Patient table, Each patient can have more than one appointments, the relation between two table is 1:*, hope this clear.

Comment: That doesn't help much. If a Binding like `Binding patient.name` queries the database, you must certainly not dispose of the current database context.

Comment: @Clemens I upload a sample example application, you can download from here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_4ruzpLLeCmv-xOGofJHi_xBkbT-X14L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to load related data:**

There are several ways that the Entity Framework can load related data into the navigation properties of an entity:

**Lazy loading**: When the entity is first read, related data isn't retrieved.

**Eager loading**: When the entity is read, related data is retrieved along with itThis typically results in a single join query that retrieves all of the data that's needed. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

So I specify `Eager loading` by using the `.include` method as following:

```
using (myEntities context = new myEntities ())
  {
      IQueryable<Appointment> query = context.Appointments.Include("patient").Where(s => s.AppointmentDate == _activeDate);
      ocAppointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(query);

      lbShiftAppointments.ItemsSource = ocAppointments.Where(s => s.DoctorShift.ShiftNumber == 1);
  }
```

Thanks for [FoggyFinder](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4651351/foggyfinder)